# Strange behavior with split(separator: )

Tags: swift, split, swift-playground

Why this line of code works in Xcode playground but not in actual Xcode project?

```
let first = string.split(separator: "").sorted().joined()
```

Error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')

I want to convert string to array of characters. `split(separator: "")` solves the problem but for some reason the code works only in my playground.
The Swift version is 5.7 in both the project and the playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're seeing this discrepancy between playgrounds and regular code, but there's a workaround that sidesteps it entirely.

When you write `string.split(separator: "")`, you get an `Array<Character>`. You can do this more directly with just `Array(string)`.

It turns out that you didn't *actually* need an array of characters. You just needed something that you could call `sorted()` on, like `Array(string).sorted()`. You're in luck, because `String` is already a `Collection<Character>` (which is why that array initializer worked in the first places), and all collections of `Comparable` values are sortable. So all you needed was `string.sorted()`

You then use `.joined()` on the result, to convert the `Array<Character>` back into a `String`. If you don't need a separator between the characters, the more straight-forward way to do that is just with the `String` initializer.

So really, all you need is:

```swift
let result = String(string.sorted())
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to convert string to array of characters

You're way overthinking this. All you need is

```
let result = string.map {$0}
```

That gives you, literally, an array of Character.

If what you really mean is that you want an array of Strings each of which represents one character, change it to

```
let result = string.map {String($0)}
```